# Unhide Downvoted Answers

Tags: script, answers

## About

This simple userscript allows you to hover over an answer that has been greyed-out because of its low score to remove the styling. After you move away from the post, it will return to its original styling.

It was inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277540/should-hovering-over-faded-answers-re-style-them-for-improved-readability) on [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

[image: Demonstration]

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6608-unhide-downvoted-answers) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/6608-unhide-downvoted-answers/code/Unhide%20Downvoted%20Answers.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/6608-unhide-downvoted-answers/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/6608-unhide-downvoted-answers/versions).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.